# what is the javascript equivalent to .get()?

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to make a go fish game in javascript. I already made it in java however I want to transfer it to javascript for a project. This is my code for java.

```
while (getTopCard() <= 27){ //adds the first 28 cards to everyone so they have 7 cards to start the game
  if (getTopCard() <= 6) players[0].setStartHand (myDeck.getDeck().get(topCard));
  else if (getTopCard() >= 7 && topCard <= 13) players[1].setStartHand (myDeck.getDeck().get(getTopCard()));
  else if (getTopCard() >= 14 && topCard <= 20) players[2].setStartHand (myDeck.getDeck().get(getTopCard()));
  else if (getTopCard() >= 21 && topCard <= 27) players[3].setStartHand (myDeck.getDeck().get(getTopCard()));
  topCard++;
}
```

This is a function in my game that is supposed to deal out 7 cards to each player. I want copied this into my js file however it throws an error because .get is not a function. What would I use as an alternative while still accomplishing the same task?

Comment: Without knows what `myDeck` is and what `getDeck()` returns, there's no way for us to help

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't be calling `getTopCard()` more than once (unless it can yield different results within the while loop).

Comment: ...what does `.get` do? You'd have to re-implement it in JS.

Comment: Just put the desired index within square brackets (like you do with players[0]).

Answer (score 0):

if I suppose that GetDeck() return an array or a list, getDeck()[topCard] should do the job. (and if I clearly understand your code, feel comfortable to tell me if it's not)

Also, if you want to be a real JS guy don't forget to use the convention and use camelCase to name your functions ;p